# Filter by one column then count unique value in another column in SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to filter data by column `Base =1` and then count the number of unique values in another column 'Animal' in SQL, data:

```
    Animal  Base  Value 
1   A       1     X     
2   B       1     X    
3   A       2     Y
4   A       3     V
```

Expected output in this case is 2 from the first two rows.

Comment: Your data has no examples of duplicate animals with the same `base`.  Is that really possible?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff It was only an example to illustrate the idea but thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler than you may have thought:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT Animal)
FROM   tbl
WHERE  Base = 1;
```

Should work in any halfway decent RDBMS including your undisclosed one. (You may have to enclose column names in double-quotes.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And to filter by `Value ` I guess I just have to using quotation marks such as this? `WHERE  Value = 'X';` ?

Comment: That is correct. Single quotes or double quotes would work for literal strings

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, assuming the table is named animals:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct Animal from animals where Base=1) tb1;
```